# Pointer to managed class member

Tags: c#, c++-cli

First, I must mention that I am not an advanced C++/C# programmer. I must do a project in C++ in which I must fill in (in a separate thread) a circular buffer with the data coming on the serial port (COMx). I did some research but I've found lot of code written in C#. So I used C++ CLR (because, from what I understood, I can have access to .net namespaces).

I searched over the internet and I've found some examples written in C# in which if I have two object of different types, I can use a pointer to another object method:

```
private void btnInit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _sensorInstance = new Sensor();
        _mySerialPort = new MySerialPort();
        _mySerialPort.DataHandler = _sensorInstance.Processing;         
    }
```

The class `MySerialPort` has the following member:

```
public Func<byte[], int> DataHandler;
```

while the `Sensor` class have the following member:

```
 public int Processing(byte[] bytes)
    {
     int l = bytes.Length;
     //code
     return l;
    }
```

The code compiles with no errors.

Now I tried to do something similar in C++.

In my `public ref class MySerialPort`

I declared:

`Func<array<Byte>^, int> ^DataHandler);`

and In my

`public ref class Sensor`

I declared:

`int Processing(array<Byte>^ bytes);`

Then, I have another `public ref class MyProject`

which have two public members:

```
Sensor ^sensor;
MySerialPort ^mySerialPort;
```

and a public method:

```
void Init()
{

    _sensor = gcnew Sensor();
    _mySerialPort = gcnew MySerialPort("COM3", 9600, 500, 500);
    _serialPort->DataHandler = _sensor->Processing;

}
```

which is called in the `int main()`: `myProjectObject.Init();`
During Build process I'm receiving the two following errors:

```
Error   1   error C3867: 'Sensor::Processing': function call missing argument list; use '&Sensor::Processing' to create a pointer to member

Error   2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int (__clrcall Sensor::* )(cli::array<unsigned char,1> ^)' to 'System::Func<cli::array<unsigned char,1> ^,int> ^'
```

I don't understand how to solve this and why in C# is possible to do it but not in C++.

I hope my long question will not bother anyone and maybe someone will explain me what I'm missing.

Best regards,

NumLock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, there are no implicit conversion from a function name to a Func or delegate. You have to explicitly call the delegate type constructor to create the Func object from the function.

Something like that:

```
_serialPort->DataHandler = 
    gcnew Func<array<Byte>^, int>(_sensor, & Sensor::Processing);
```